# Json operator doesn't seem to work with variable

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb

Test query:

```
select * from testarray(1120,'{"oserial":
["10002695","10002692"],"nserial":[{"serial":"10002693","price":"180.00"},
{"serial":"10002697","price":"180.00"}]}');
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.testarray(salesid int,items json) 
RETURNS int
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare
  resu text;
  resu2 text := 'TH';
  ssrow RECORD;
  oserlen int := 0;
  counter int := 0;
begin
  select json_array_length(items::json->'oserial') into oserlen;
  while counter < oserlen loop
    -- if I change 0 to counter, this function does not work
    select (items::json#>>'{oserial,0}') into resu; 
    select * into ssrow 
    from salesserial 
    where fk_salesid=salesid 
      and serialnum=resu::int;

    insert into stockloct(serialnum,fk_barcode,source,exflag) 
    values(ssrow.serialnum,ssrow.fk_barcode,ssrow.fk_salesid,true);

    counter := counter + 1;
  end loop; 
  select items::json#>'{nserial,0,serial}' into resu2;
  return oserlen;
end;
$$;
```

I am testing PostgreSQL functions.

This particular line below doesn't seem to work, can someone help me. Thanks in advance. I am using Postgresql version 9.5. If I change the 0 to counter variable in the json string, the select doesn't return value. It only works with number, not variables.

```
select (items::json#>>'{oserial,0}') into resu; 
-- if i change 0 to counter variable, this select returns null i think as the insert below the line fails;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right-hand argument for `#>>` is a text array. Replace

```
select (items::json#>>'{oserial,0}') into resu;
```

with

```
select items::json#>>array['nserial',counter::text] into resu;
```